# Set Current Pose As Shape Key

Tags: animation, rigging, shape-keys, pose-mode

I would like to be able to set my character in certain poses and then convert those poses into individual shape keys (or as a rigged bone) to save animation time.  This is not for animating the entire character, but for changing the shape of the eyes.
I want to be able to have shape keys to get certain poses, but I also want to be able to hand-shape it using the rig as needed.
Thanks!

Comment: if you create a pose with the armature, you can go in the Armature modifier and, on the dropdown menu, click on Save As Shapekey, it will create the corresponding shapekey in the Shape Keys list

Answer (score 3):

Inside the Armature modifier, there is an option called Save as Shapekey. Use that.

Comment: This works, but it also requires me to reparent the mesh to the armature.  How can I reapply the armature using the already-created mesh groups?  The mesh groups have the predefined weight paints.